# Items in QGridLayout won't wrap

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout

I have created a simple GridLayout in QML, and added 10 buttons into the grid. The gridlayout is anchored to the parent.  I have set a Layout.minimumWidth and Layout.maximumWidth for each button.

I was EXPECTING that when I resized the window, the GridLayout would wrap my buttons so that I would only every see the number of buttons in a row that can fit evenly within a row (based on min/max width set above), and the number rows would increase as the number of columns decreases (based on window size)

When I'm experiencing is that the buttons go off endlessly to the right, and resizing the window only crops the number of buttons shown.

I suspect I am misunderstanding something.  Isn't this the purpose of GridLayout - to wrap at the best item to keep columns neatly in view?  If so, why doesn't this work?

Comment: No, that's not how `QGridLayout` works.  Instead you might want to have a look at the [flow layout example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

Comment: Since I want the items to stack into columns, wrapping as the window resizes, can I combine Flow Layout with something to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by G.M. `GridLayout` doesn't recalculate the number of columns automatically.

The best/easiest solution is the manually calculate the desired number of columns based on your `Layout.minimumWidth` (pseudo-code):

```
GridLayout
{
  ...
  column: width_cell / width_grid
  ...
}
```